# Как тестировать методы для работы с бд?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, юнит-тесты

В своем приложении я использую [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) версии 6.1.3 для работы с БД [mssql](/questions/tagged/mssql).

Назрел вопрос *покрытия* своего кода тестами.

Подскажите,пожалуйста, способы тестирования для данной связки.

Мне в голову приходит создание локальной тестовой БД, наполнение её данными и тестирование методов на данной БД, при данном подходе я смогу проверить как методы получения данных так и *CRUD* методы.

Так же я слышал что для тестирования методов для работы с БД можно создать `generic` репозиторий `public interface IRepository<T> where T: class { }`
и для тестирования подсовывать `fake` репозиторий с тестовыми данными.

Я пока склоняюсь больше к первому сценарию, т.е. созданию локальной тестовой БД, которая будет подвержена тем же изменениям что и реальнай бд(засчет механизма миграций в ef).

Подскажите насколько *правильным* будет тестирование описанным мной способом? Буду рад услышать о других способах.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Тестирование — это процесс исследования и испытания программного
>   обеспечения (ПО), преследующий две основные задачи: убедиться в том, что ПО
>   рабочее и соответствует требованиям, а также выявить ситуации, в
>   которых поведение ПО является неправильным, нежелательным или не
>   соответствует начальным требованиям.

---

Вы рассматриваете два варианта тестирования. Для того, чтобы выявить более подходящий, необходимо выяснить плюсы и минусы обоих подходов и отталкиваясь от полученных результатов сделать выбор. Я всего лишь Вам посоветую, а выберете Вы сами.

---

### Вариант #1

***Создание локальной тестовой БД, которая будет подвержена тем же изменениям что и реальная БД(за счет механизма миграций в EF)***

Данный подход может существовать, но глядя на него возникают вопросы, а готовы ли Вы пожертвовать некоторыми недостатками этого подхода? К недостаткам я бы отнес:

1. Прямая зависимость тестов от данных, хранящихся в БД
2. Пересечение данных для нескольких тестов. Бывают такие ситуации, в тестах, когда мы имитируем ошибку или ожидаем неправильное поведение - это вполне нормально. Но как быть в этом случае? У нас будут данные и хорошие и *плохие*.
3. Зависимость от миграций. Тут несколько подпунктов. **Первый**: если забудем сделать миграцию - упадут тесты. **Вторая**: необходимо всегда помнить про то, что нужно сделать миграцию и для тестов. **Третья**: сопровождение таких тестов. Что будет делать новый программист?
4. Что если БД вдруг *упала*? Тесты снова не работают.
5. Данный подход не назовешь простым, имеются свои сложности.
6. Думаю, что это тоже стоит вписать, в комментарии увидел: *Для проверки миграции всегда можно держать бэкап нужной версии*

---

### Вариант #2

***Для тестирования методов для работы с бд можно создать generic репозиторий public interface IRepository where T: class { } и для тестирования подсовывать fake репозиторий с тестовыми данными.***

Это более удобный вариант тестирования, на мой взгляд. Давайте рассмотрим почему:

1. Мы не зависим от данных в БД, так как данные подготавливаются в самих тестах.
2. Данные не пересекаются, мы всегда знаем, что тесты работают только с тем, что мы им *подсунем*.
3. Имитация ситуаций, когда мы ожидаем ошибку не ломает наши тесты и не приводит к проблемам.
4. Простота использования. Не нужно делать миграций. Есть много документации, которая проиллюстрирует примеры использования моков (фэйков).
5. Скорость тестирования. Тут очень большое преимущество у моков(фэйков). Они работаю намного быстрее.

Есть некий недостаток этого подхода, как мне сказали - это тестирование логики, которая заложена в БД: индексы, конкурентный доступ и т.п.

---

### Вариант #3

Можно объединить эти подходы, вывести что-то промежуточное. К примеру перед запуском писать данные в базу - это подготовка данных. Затем работать с конкретной БД, в которой лежат наши данные, то есть своего рода БД для тестов. Главное не забывать *убирать за собой* - удалять данные, которые используются для теста. Такой подход довольно громоздкий и тоже не простой.

Использование такого подхода подразумевает под собой написание вспомогательной плюшки, которая будет *помогать*. Это поможет тестировать CRUD методы. Но тут возникает и другой вопрос: кто будет тестировать вспомогательную утилиту? То есть и такой подход имеет место быть.

---

Ну и еще один вопрос: Вы собираетесь тестировать Ваш код или EF?

Если вести разработку по *Test Driven Development*, то использование фэйков существенно упрощает разработку.

Я не хочу конкретно акцентировать свое внимание на одном варианте, я всего лишь хочу посоветовать сделать выбор, который будет более правильным и в дальнейшем не вызовет проблем. Чтобы спустя время Вы не оглянулись на проделанную работу и не сказали себе "*А почему я не пошел другим путем?*".

Выбор необходимо делать основываясь на поставленной задаче. Использовать только один подход вряд ли получится - скорее всего необходимо использовать несколько подходов.

Comment: а если совместить эти два подхода как написал @Monk, т.е. для каждого теста инсертить в бд тестовые данные и после себя убираться, да этот тест будет выполняться дольше но в некоторых случаях он будет более полным?

Comment: @Bald, я использовал данный подход - тоже не совсем удобно. Зависимость от БД остается (бывало отрубалась сеть и доступа не было - все падало), да и скорость тоже меньше моков. Я пробовал первый, второй и комбинированный варианты. Остановился на моках.

Comment: Как минус второго метода - то, что вы не тестируете EF, не значит, что с EF всё хорошо. Вы просто не знаете, как он себя чувствует. Иногда какой нибудь кеш ORM может запороть вполне валидный на фейках код.

Comment: *Вы собираетесь тестировать Ваш код или EF?* ответ на этот вопрос следующий: я хочу тестировать не только методы но и логику которая заложена в бд: индексы, конкурентный доступ, ну и т.п.

Comment: @Bald, я просто не вижу смысла тестировать EF. А по поводу индексов и тестирования БД, да тут есть некий недостаток.

Comment: пример из жизни `var currentActState = _context.Set<Act>().Where(x=>x.Id==actid).Include(x=>x.History).Single().Select(x=>x.History.Last())` при тестировании на тестовых данных возвращает правильный результат, этот же запрос в бд в некоторых случаях ведет себя некорректно, добавив явную сортировку перед `Last()` проблема решилась, поэтому я и хочу тестирования совместно с бд

Comment: @Bald, тогда использование подхода, где мы пишем данные в базу, а затем используем эти данные в тестах - имеет место быть, но тут нужно пойти на некоторые жертвы. Никто не запрещает вести разработку используя все подходы. Просто не стоит сильно увлекаться и зависеть от БД.

Comment: @DenisBubnov основной минус варианта #2 - мелкие отличия в работе Linq to SQL/EF и Linq to Objects (моки). Особенно в обработке null-ов. И наоборот - код Linq to Objects спокойно проглотит Func вместо Expression, что при нужном уровне невезения, вычитает в память половину базы. Т.е. проблема этого метода не столько в отсутствии покрытия для индексов (их ничто не покроет), сколько в дырявости абстракции LINQ.

Comment: @PashaPash, да тут Вы несомненно правы. Обработка null - достаточно весомая проблема. Что касается индексов и прочего - тут никак не получается... Но исходя из логики я бы все же использовал разные подходы. По большей степени моки, по меньшей - базу для тестов.

Answer (score 4):

Перечисленные вами способы относятся к разным видам тестирования. Создание базы и запросы к ней — интеграционное тестирование. Создание базы, её наполнение, прохождение тестов — всё это будет отнимать много времени и вы не захотите запускать эти тесты ежеминутно. С другой стороны, эти тесты можно включить в процесс сборки (интеграции, непрерывной интеграции). Если у вас нет сервера непрерывной интеграции, запускайте их вручную, просто реже. Чтобы сделать это, пометьте их атрибутом `TestCategory`, или разместите все в одной сборке: Visual Studio позволит вам запускать тесты только из отдельного проекта или только одной категории.

Второй вариант — модульное тестирование (unit testing). Именно модульные тесты запускаются постоянно и они, естественно, не должны выполнять длительные операции: обращаться к файлам, обращаться к сетевым ресурсам, к серверу баз данных. Именно в этих тестах используют mock и stub-объекты (они же fake).

Поэтому мой ответ: вам придётся делать и те, и другие тесты. Теперь о том, как это делать.

#### Модульные тесты (unit tests)

Очень часто программисты задают вопрос — как мне модульно протестировать Entity Framework? Ответ: никак, модульные тесты на Entity Framework пишут его разработчики, а вы пишите тесты на свой код. Ошибкой также будет написание сложных тестов, которые значительно сложнее вашего кода.

```
public class EfUserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory;

    public EfUserRepository(IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
    {
        this.dbContextFactory = dbContextFactory;
    }

    public UserData ReadById(int id)
    {
        using (var dbContext = _dbContextFactory.Create())
        {
            return dbContext.Users.Single(u => u.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Что вы действительно можете протестировать в этом коде? Сразу хочется протестировать работу `Single` и убедиться, что метод вернёт один-единственный ответ или выдаст исключение. Но `Single` — не ваш код, более того, по некоторым причинам, довольно трудно проверить его вызов, поскольку это метод расширения, а не метод интерфейса `IQueryable`. Но вы можете проверить, что у `dbContextFactory` будет вызыван метод `Create` и у созданного контекста будет обращение к свойству `Users`. Вот как это можно сделать просто, с помощью библиотеки **Moq**

```
public void ReadById_WhenCalled_CallsDbContextFactoryCreate()
{
    var dbContextFactoryMock = new Mock<IDbContextFactory>();
    var dbContextFactory = dbContextFactoryMock.Object;

    var userRepository = new EfUserRepository(dbContextFactory);

    var user = userRepository.ReadById(1);

    dbContextFactoryMock.Verify(x => x.Create());
}
```

#### Интеграционное тестирование (integrating testing)

Здесь вам потребуется база и реальные запросы. Именно в интеграционном тестировании вы проверяете код в целом — создаете запись в таблице, потом читаете и убеждаетесь, что она там есть.

Ваш вопрос — как заполнить эту базу, и основных отета здесь два: вы можете либо отдельно заполнить базу тестовыми данными и отдельно писать тесты, и вы можете в каждом тесте создавать свой тестовый набор данных (создавать нужные записи в таблицах). Второй вариант кажется плохим — будет много лишних записей, тесты будут работать долго. Но, если ваш проект большой, это единственное решение, поскольку вы довольно быстро запутаетесь, потому что заполнение базы будет в одном месте, а использование — в нескольких других местах.

Но сейчас, как я понимаю, вы работаете над проектом один и таблиц там в пределах десяти-пятнадцати? Подойдёт первый вариант.

Надо ли чистить базу после тестов? Можно, но в большинстве работающих проектов удаление данные приводит к проблемам. Обычное решение — всё-таки запускать тесты на отдельной базе, может быть даже на каждый раз новой.

Лучше всего навесить интеграционное тестирование на макроопределение, похожее на `DEBUG`, например, на `DB_INTEGRATION`. В миграциях Entity Framework (в папке `Migrations`) лежит класс `Configuration`, у которого есть метод `Seed`. Этот метод вызывается для заполнения данных.

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DispatcherDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(DbContext context)
    {
        FillTestData(context);
    }

    [Conditional("DB_INTEGRATION")]
    private void FillTestData(DbContext context)
    {
        // с помощью context.AddOrUpdate добавляем тестовые записи
        // во все таблицы

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Вставляем метод `FillTestData` и навешиваем на него атрибут `Conditional`, благодаря которому метод будет вызываться и вставляться в сборку только в том случае, если объявлено макроопределение `DB_INTEGRATION`.

Точно такой же атрибут надо добавить на все интеграционные тестовые методы, которые будут обращаться к этим данным.

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("Integration")]
[Conditional("DB_INTEGRATION")]
public void UserCreation()
{
    var dbContextFactory = new DbContextFactory();
    var userRepository = new EfUserRepository(dbContextFactory);

    var username = Utils.GenerateRandomString(200);
    var user1 = userRepository.Create(username);
    var user2 = userRepository.ReadById(user1.Id);

    Assert.AreEqual(user1.Name, user2.Name);
}
```

Теперь зайдите на страницу свойств тестового проекта, и на вкладке **Build** впишите `DB_INTEGRATION` в список **Conditional compilation symbols**. После перекомпиляции проекта, в базе появятся тестовые данные, а в панели тестов — тесты. В Test Explorer левая верхняя кнопка **Group By**, выбирайте **Group By Traits** и тесты категории `Integration` будут показаны в отдельной группе, которую и можно будет запустить. Обычные модульные тесты окажутся в группе **No Traits**, так что их удобно будет запускать отдельно от интеграционных тестов и часто.

#### Можно ли сделать интеграционное тестирование быстрым?

Вот если очень хочется сделать реальный тест обращений к базе, но чтобы работало быстро? Да, возможно.

Второй вопрос: модульные тесты должны работать даже в случае, если у вас нет никаких внешних сервисов и баз данных, можно ли проводить тестирование без внешнего сервера БД? Тоже да.

Многие современные СУБД позволяют хранить базы в памяти. Некоторые СУБД специально спроектированы так, чтобы эмулировать работу внешнего сервера, хотя они встроены в ваше приложение, см. например SQLite и SQL Server Compact Edition.

Эти тесты всё ещё не будут модульными по сути, но по быстродействию будут на уровне модульных, и их можно будет запускать часто.

Начните изучения вопроса с
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce
https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/

Comment: если честно совсем не понял примера с модульным тестированием

Comment: Пример с тестированием репозитория - бред. **Тесты должны отталкиваться от спецификации, а не от реализации!** Репозиторий, по спецификации, должен хранить данные - к примеру, если туда сохранить объект - его можно будет потом достать его по id. **Требования вызывать Create() и получать Users к репозиторию никто не ставил.**

Comment: @Bald правильно сделали, что не поняли

Comment: @PavelMayorov, зачем оскроблять? Слово **бред** не очень хорошо подходит в технической дискуссии. В данном случае речь идёт о тестировании не спецификации а конкретной реализации через EntityFramework. Протестировать спецификацию вам удастся только в интеграционном тесте. Поэтому ваше утверждение я бы переформулировал. Когда возможно, тесты должны отталкиваться от спецификации, но возможно это не всегда.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko тест, который отталкивается от реализации, не имеет смысла

Comment: @Bald что именно не понятно?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Ваши утверждения на какие-то лозунги похожи. Тест имеет тот смысл, что если в реализацию будут внесены разрушающие изменения, например, копи-пастом, он их покажет.

Comment: мне не понятно что Мы тестируем/для чего в примере модульного теста

Comment: @MarkShevchenko неправда, внесший разрушающие изменения в реализацию скажет "ой" и внесет разрушающие изменения в тест. И никто это не заметит, потому что нет критерия что должно быть в тесте.

Comment: @Bald, мы тестируем то, что можем протестировать в модульном тесте. Смотрим на код, и понимаем, что там есть два важных момента. В приведённом примере проверяется первый, так как в модульных тестах рекомендуют проверять в каждом только что-то одно. Теперь если кто-то изменит код метода и забудет вызвать `dbContextFactory.Create`, тест это покажет.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я совсем не понял вашей реплики. Если кто-то исправит код метода и забудет вызвать `Create`, тест это покажет. Именно в этом смысл этого модульного теста.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko а почему вы так уверены, что вызов `dbContextFactory.Create` так важен для правильной работы метода?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я много времени потратил на написание поста, и не хочу его больше тратить на препирательства. Вы свою позицию высказали, она здесь останется. Можете заминусовать пост. Я не считаю, что вы правы, поскольку в этом случае ни о каких моках и стабах не было бы речи, они используются именно для тестирования реализации. Если этот аргумент не кажется вам правильным, другого предложить не могу.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Вы пишете по поводу репозитория: *Репозиторий, по спецификации, должен хранить данные - к примеру, если туда сохранить объект - его можно будет потом достать его по id*. Мне кажется или тут есть одна небольшая неточность? Просто я думаю, что репозиторий это интерфейс для доступа к данным, то есть он инкасулирует в себе логику работы с БД, а не представляет саму БД.

Comment: @DenisBubnov Это одно и то же.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, видимо мое определение репозитория просто не накладывается на Ваше. От этого и возник вопрос.

Comment: @DenisBubnov ну все просто же. Если репозиторий инкапсулирует работу с БД - значит, использующий репозиторий код про БД ничего не знает. Но тогда и спецификация на репозиторий не должна содержать БД, с точки зрения остальных модулей репозиторий хранить в себе все данные, то что там есть какая-то еще БД - это просто деталь реализации.

Comment: @Bald Нашёл статью на MSDN, которая как раз раскрывает способы модульного тестирования Entity Framework с помощью Mock: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn314429.aspx

Comment: @MarkShevchenko спасибо за ссылку

Answer (score 3):

Придумывать обертку над EF только для того, чтобы при тестировании не зависеть от БД - не самая лучшая идея. Потому что эту обертку тоже кто-то должен тестировать :)

Поэтому если у вас нет отдельного DAL - тестировать надо на отдельной тестовой БД. Поддерживать ее в актуальном состоянии - не проблема, создать базу и накатить миграции можно прямо в тестах. Можно это делать в каком-нибудь [SetUpFixture](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute)

Если же у вас есть отдельный DAL - то его надо тестировать точно так же, на тестовой базе. А вот все, что выше DAL - уже можно тестировать подменой DAL.

PS Если тестируемый класс не управляет соединениями и транзакциями внутри - можно провести тест внутри транзакции, а потом откатить ее - это решит проблему накопления ошибок в тестовой БД.

Comment: *Придумывать обертку над EF только для того, чтобы при тестировании не зависеть от БД - не самая лучшая идея.* - ничего придумывать не нужно, можно пользоваться готовыми решениями. *Поддерживать ее в актуальном состоянии - не проблема* - если в команде один программист, который обо всем помнит и у него кроме одного теста ничего нет - тогда да, в противном случае - это не так. *провести тест внутри транзакции, а потом откатить ее* - тесты должны быть простыми и понятными, использование там еще и транзакций уже больше похоже на лишний код.

Comment: @DenisBubnov *"если в команде один программист, который обо всем помнит и у него кроме одного теста ничего нет - тогда да, в противном случае - это не та"* - а какие проблемы могут возникнуть?

Comment: @DenisBubnov *"использование там еще и транзакций уже больше похоже на лишний код"* в тесте - не только похоже, но и является. В базовом классе для тестов - совсем не лишний код, а элемент инфраструктуры тестирования.

Comment: *а какие проблемы могут возникнуть* - когда проект большой с несколькими ветками (dev, test, preproduction и production) - то сопровождение еще и базы под тесты проблематично. Если программист, сопровождающий эту БД заболел или уволился, что тогда делать? Лично я за простую и сопровождаемую архитектуру.

Comment: *В базовом классе для тестов - совсем не лишний код, а элемент инфраструктуры тестирования* - смотря что будет тестироваться. Но тут я и соглашусь и нет.

Comment: @DenisBubnov какая разница сколько БД сопровождать - если у них у всех одна и та же схема? Сопровождающий БД программист пишет скрипты - а они уже накатываются на БД автоматически. Тестовая БД в этом плане вообще самая удобная - ее при любой ошибке можно прибить и развернуть заново.

Comment: *можно прибить и развернуть заново* - да, но это процесс не такой уж быстрый. *Сопровождающий БД программист пишет скрипты* - можно генерировать через миграции с использованием аттрибута `-force`. *они уже накатываются на БД автоматически* - они не накатятся автоматически, если их делают руками. Даже те, которые сгенерированы автоматически - все равно на других базах запускаются руками.

Comment: @DenisBubnov это уже ошибка процесса разработки, что не накатываются. Надо ее исправлять, а не молиться на нее. У нас вот все накатывается. Про миграции я не упомянул для упрощения.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а можно пример того, как они будут накатываться автоматически. Миграции, которые мы делаем в основном проекте, которые будут накатываться на другую БД, в рамках тестового проекта.Что-то я себе это не могу представить. Дадите пример - буду благодарен.

Comment: @DenisBubnov что значит - "на другую БД"? У вас что, одна БД на всех?.. Я думаю, вам стоит задать отдельный вопрос, или перейти в чат.

Comment: Да тут так не объяснить...нет, на каждую ветку своя БД. Было еще использование БД в тестах, но перешел на моки. Отдельный вопрос...ну не знаю, просто автоматическое выполнение скриптов на уровне запуска тестов, если база отличается - что-то из рода фантастики.

Comment: @DenisBubnov даже стратегию инициализации [MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx) ни разу не видели?..

Comment: Ну это же автоматическая миграция БД в EF, знаю про это. Мы с Вами о разном говорим. я Вам про другое. Это совершенно другой вопрос. Может быть как-нибудь соберусь с мыслями и задам вопрос на SO. Но пока, мне кажется, что это все же мои мечты. Что касаемо изменения схемы данных - я не доверяю автоматическим миграциям, уж так сложилось.

Comment: @DenisBubnov э... вы не доверяете самому механизму миграций или генератору автомиграций? Второй можно и в "ручной" режим перевести, более того - только в таком режиме нормальная работа с несколькими БД и возможна.

Comment: я работаю в ручном режиме миграций. Генерирую скрипты во время применения миграции и храню `SQL`, который получаю через `force`, чтобы от версии к версии применять эти скрипты на следующих БД (*test*, *production*), а разработка ведется на *development-версии* (или просто *Current*)

Comment: @DenisBubnov зря вы так делаете - сами себе лишнюю работу создаете же. Кстати, [FluentMigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator/wiki), который мы применяем на некоторых проектах, умеет работать с sql-скриптами (собственно, в таком режиме и работаем с ним).

Answer (score 2):

По возможности, полноценные тесты должны быть аналогичны работе реального приложения.

Т.е. на запуск тестов создается база, как она создается для реальной работы, накачивается данными необходимыми для работы (и тестовыми, если нужно нагрузочное тестирование). Дальше, соответственно идёт имитация работы клиента - подключение, выполнение операций, получение результатов и их проверка на валидность.

Стоит иметь в виду, что некоторые тесты начинают пересекаться по данным, поэтому, по возможности стоит удалять данные за тестом. Т.е. тест сам создает себе тестовые данные, сам их обрабатывает и проверяет, а потом ещё и сам удаляет, для минимизации влияния своих данных на другие тесты.

Как примерно выглядит такой тест:

```
[TestMethod]
public void RegisterLetter()
{
  this.Given(_ => this.GivenNewlyLetter())
    .And(_ => this.GivenNewlyDocumentRegister(DocumentFlow.Incoming))
    .When(_ => this.WhenRegisterDocument(this.letter))
    .Then(_ => this.LetterShouldBeRegistred())
    .TearDownWith(_ => this.DeleteLetter())
    .TearDownWith(_ => this.DeleteDocumentRegister())
    .BDDfy();
}
```

Создаем письмо, создаем для него журнал. Регистрируем в журнале письмо, проверяем, что регистрация успешна. Удаляем письмо, удаляем журнал. Удаление сущностей происходит в любом случае, хоть успешен тест, хоть нет.

Ещё один серьезный плюс такого подхода в том, что если у вас не разворачивается новая база, вы об этом узнаете быстро.

Есть и серьезный минус, на который я пока так и не нашел удобного решения. Если у вас нет возможности почистить базу после теста (бизнес-ограничение, которое не получается обойти легально и просто), то делать связанные тесты на эти же данные становится сложнее.

---

Тестирование вторым способом, через Моки\Фейки будет быстрее, потому как не надо будет стучаться в базу, но и пользы от него будет меньше, потому что соединение с базой и какие то специфические особенности EF могут быть упущены. С другой стороны, если вы хотите тестировать бизнес логику приложения и на особенности хранения в базе вам без разницы - это отличный вариант, который намного легче развернуть, запустить и получить результаты.

Стоит иметь в виду, что так нельзя тестировать например нагрузку, потому как вы выкинули целый слой приложения. Так нельзя тестировать сложные запросы, потому как EF их в SQL завернёт, где то упадёт при материализации и прочее, а тут у вас фейк, который работает в памяти и врядли будет имитировать любую ORM с достаточной достоверностью.

Собственно, плюсы этого тестирования, на мой взгляд, сильно проседают под реальностью.

---

Как вывод - на мой взгляд, тесты должны быть клиентскими в первую очередь.
Т.е. работать так, как будет работать клиент - авторизация, операция, результат, проверка, выход.
Пока не меняется клиентский интерфейс, ему одновременно неважно, что спрятано в базе данных, и одновременно он проверяет сразу все слои приложения.
Естественно, тут возникает проблема, что развернуть такого клиента гораздо сложнее, чем просто написать тест на функцию, которой скормили параметр и получили результат. С другой стороны, разворачивание такого клиента обычно почти равнозначно разворачиванию реального клиента, унифицировать не так уж и сложно.

И да, не стоит сильно задумываться над тем, как за собой почистить базу. В большинстве случаев, достаточно развернуть чистую базу и дропнуть её за собой.
А когда данные от других тестов начинают влиять друг на друга - у вас они либо и реальному клиенту мешают, либо тест недостаточно корректно изображает из себя клиента.