# Юнит тесты Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Хочу протестировать сервисы работы с БД через EF.

Тестовый метод:

RoleService service = new RoleService(new RoleRepository());

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestGetAllAsync()
{
   IEnumerable<Role> roles = service.GetAll();
   Assert.IsNotNull(roles);
}
```

Метод сервиса

```
public IEnumerable<Role> GetAll()
{
    return _db.Roles.ToArray();
}
```

при отладке теста получаю ошибку

Message: Метод теста UnitTestTMSMVC.RolesServiceTest.TestGetAllAsync создал исключение: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The model backing the 'DataContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269)..

Т.е. требует наличия EF в проекте теста. Я поставил его, он потребовал контекст и классы моделей. Я перетянул, дальше 
он потребовал обновить БД, что не вариант (как и предыдущие действия).

Как мне протестировать такой метод?

---

Сделал поместил тесты в рабочем проекте, проблема ушла. Спасибо ответившим!

Comment: Есть хорошая рекомендация, что не нужно покрывать тестами ваш ORM, он уже и так покрыт тестами от разработчиков.

Comment: попробуйте почитать мой аналогичный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/559591/179270)

Comment: обычно используют репозиторий, тогда для метода репозитория  rolesRepository.GetAll() можно сделать Mock, и вы сможете протестировать ваш сервис

Comment: @pashagoroshko Автор как раз хочет написать тест на GetAll репозитория, а не тестировать сервис, использующий этот репозиторий. В этом плане ему больше подходит ссылка которую Bald кинул.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста пример того, как вы инициализируете _db, а еще лучше сделайте минимальный проект показывающий проблему, выложите на гитхабе и добавьте ссылку на него в свой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Тесты на настоящей БД - это уже не юнит-тесты, а интеграционные (тестируем весь DAL, включая миграции, а не отдельные изолированные типы).

Тут есть два пути:

1. использовать EF Core (который поддерживает .NET Standard 2.0), тогда будет возможно использовать [InMemory Database](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/)-провайдер.
2. Делать абстракцию над `DbContext`, скармливая репозиториям вместо
   него правильно заточенные Mock'и.
3. Не тестить DAL вообще, делать его максимально тонким, вынося логику
   в сервисный слой